# Exporting CSV from Django/Graphql

Tags: django, graphql, export-to-csv

I need to generate and output a csv file/data from my db data to my frontend.

I found this and followed the instructions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/outputting-csv/

However, I am using graphql and graphene. The instructions above don't say in what format the output should be returned. When I return plain `String`, all I get returned is `"<HttpResponse status_code=200, \"text/csv\">"`.

Example of code:

```
class Query:
    users_csv = graphene.String()
    ...

    @classmethod
    @login_required
    def resolve_users_csv(cls, obj, info):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type="text/csv")
        writer = csv.writer(response)

        header = [
            "EmployeeEmail",
            "TeamMemberName",
            "PhoneNumber",
            "MobileNumber",
            "IsAdmin",
        ]
        content = []
        for u in User.objects.filter(customer=info.context.user.customer):
            content.append(
                [
                    str(u.email) if u.email else "",
                    str(u.get_full_name()),
                    str(u.phone_number) if u.phone_number else "",
                    str(u.mobile_number) if u.mobile_number else "",
                    str(u.is_admin),
                ]
            )

        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerows(content)
        return response
```

Any help or pointers is very appreciated...

Comment: Solved here:
[Using GraphQL machinery, but return CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66392161/14427117)

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the file too, which is the csv. The line below will make it downloadable.

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="yourfilename.csv"'
```